# Room auto-migration with rename columns failing (NOT NULL constraint failed, bad generated Migration class)

Tags: android, android-room, android-room-migration

I recently renamed columns in my Room entity, by prefixing the word `setting_` on the columns:

[image: diff of the changes]

Amongst some other changes this is the auto migration impl it has produced:

```
class AppDatabase_AutoMigration_15_16_Impl extends Migration {
private final AutoMigrationSpec callback = new SettingsRenamedColumnsAutoMigration();

public AppDatabase_AutoMigration_15_16_Impl() {
    super(15, 16);
}

public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `merchants` ADD COLUMN `accessLevel` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merchantSettings` (`setting_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_group_id` INTEGER, `setting_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_value` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_data_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`setting_id`), FOREIGN KEY(`setting_group_id`) REFERENCES `merchants`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )");
    database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_merchantSettings_setting_group_id` ON `merchantSettings` (`setting_group_id`)");
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_new_branchSettings` (`setting_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_branch_id` INTEGER, `setting_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_value` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_data_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`setting_id`), FOREIGN KEY(`setting_branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `_new_branchSettings` (`setting_type`,`setting_updated_at`) SELECT `setting_type`,`updated_at` FROM `branchSettings`");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `branchSettings`");
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `_new_branchSettings` RENAME TO `branchSettings`");
    database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_branchSettings_setting_branch_id` ON `branchSettings` (`setting_branch_id`)");
    DBUtil.foreignKeyCheck(database, "branchSettings");
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_new_branches` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `address` TEXT, `lat` TEXT, `lng` TEXT, `is_default` INTEGER, `email` TEXT, `phone` TEXT, `clover_category_id` TEXT, `clover_gift_item` TEXT, `clover_cashless_item` TEXT, `prep_time` INTEGER, `opening_hours` TEXT, `currency_code` TEXT, `created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, `updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `_new_` (`id`,`name`,`address`,`lat`,`lng`,`is_default`,`email`,`phone`,`prep_time`,`opening_hours`,`currency_code`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) SELECT `id`,`name`,`address`,`lat`,`lng`,`is_default`,`email`,`phone`,`prep_time`,`opening_hours`,`currency_code`,`created_at`,`updated_at` FROM `branches`");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `branches`");
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `_new_` RENAME TO `branches`");
    this.callback.onPostMigrate(database);
}
```

}

With the following auto migration spec:

```
AutoMigration(
        from = 15,
        to = 16,
        spec = AppDatabase.SettingsRenamedColumnsAutoMigration::class
    )


    @RenameColumn.Entries(
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "id",
        toColumnName = "setting_id"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "branch_id",
        toColumnName = "setting_branch_id"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "name",
        toColumnName = "setting_name"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "value",
        toColumnName = "setting_value"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "data_type",
        toColumnName = "setting_data_type"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "created_at",
        toColumnName = "setting_created_at"
    ),
    RenameColumn(
        tableName = "branchSettings",
        fromColumnName = "updated_at",
        toColumnName = "setting_updated_at"
    ),
)
@DeleteColumn.Entries(
    DeleteColumn(tableName = "branches", columnName = "checkout_category_id")
)
class SettingsRenamedColumnsAutoMigration : AutoMigrationSpec
```

This error is affecting every updater I think:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: _new_branchSettings.setting_name (code 1299 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_NOTNULL)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:831)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:756)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:66)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1806)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1733)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:255)
    at loylap.core.sdk.data.local.db.AppDatabase_AutoMigration_15_16_Impl.migrate(AppDatabase_AutoMigration_15_16_Impl.java:31)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.kt:91)
```

I don't know enough MySQL/Room to confirm but it looks like the 15->16 Migration class has at least 2 issues. It creates a `_new_branchSettings` table, but only inserts 2 random columns (`setting_type` and `setting_updated_at`). Should it not be inserting everything here? Hence the error - `setting_name` is supposed to be not null.

Also, I am very suspicious of ``` INSERT INTO ``_new_`` ``` ... What is `_new_` and who created it? To me that looks like a typo and it should be inserting into `_new_branches`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does appear to be a possible bug. You may wish to report this as a bug.

As you have suggested the INSERT INTO appears to be omitting columns and thus the values, due to the columns being omitted, will be null.

I've looked at the ``` INSERT INTO ``_new_`` ```  and that (without extremely close inspection) appears to be fine albeit not the best naming convention (perhaps a bug but with just the 1 it probably will not cause an issue).

Personally, perhaps being even more suspicious than yourself, my solution would be to manually migrate, which would change the INSERT INTO for the new branch settings table to insert default values if nulls are found (just correcting by extracting from and assigning values to all columns would be enough).

- I've come across previous issues with migrations and would suggest that changes do go in that are not that well tested.

**A Solution** as a manual migration rather than an AutoMigration, would be to use (note not tested so it is ***in-principle** code) :-

```
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `merchants` ADD COLUMN `accessLevel` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
  database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `merchantSettings` (`setting_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_group_id` INTEGER, `setting_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_value` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_data_type` TEXT NOT NULL, `setting_created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, `setting_updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`setting_id`), FOREIGN KEY(`setting_group_id`) REFERENCES `merchants`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )");
  database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_merchantSettings_setting_group_id` ON `merchantSettings` (`setting_group_id`)");
  
  /* SPLIT to make the code more readable */
  database.execSQL(
          "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_new_branchSettings` " +
                  "(`setting_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_branch_id` INTEGER, " +
                  "`setting_type` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_name` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_value` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_data_type` TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                  "`setting_updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                  "PRIMARY KEY(`setting_id`), " +
                  "FOREIGN KEY(`setting_branch_id`) REFERENCES `branches`(`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE " +
                  ")"
  );
  /* SPLIT to make the code more readable */
  database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `_new_branchSettings` (" +
          "`setting_id`," +
          "`setting_branch_id`," +
          "`setting_type`," +
          "`setting_name`," +
          "`setting_value`," +
          "`setting_data_type`," +
          "`setting_created_at`," +
          "`setting_updated_at`" +
          ") " +
          "SELECT " +
          "`id`," +
          "`branch_id`," +
          "coalesce(`settng_type`,'SETTING_TYPEWASNULL')," +
          "coalesce(`name`,'NAMEWASNULL')," +
          "coalesce(`value`,'VALUEWASNULL')," +
          "coalesce(`data_type`,'DATA_TYPEWASNULL')," +
          "coalesce(`created_at`,-9999)," +
          "coalsce(`updated_at`,-8888) " +
          "FROM `branchSettings`" +
          "");
  /* Above INSERT replaces the following suspicious INSERT INTO */
  //database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `_new_branchSettings` (`setting_type`,`setting_updated_at`) SELECT `setting_type`,`updated_at` FROM `branchSettings`");
  database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `branchSettings`");
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `_new_branchSettings` RENAME TO `branchSettings`");
  database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_branchSettings_setting_branch_id` ON `branchSettings` (`setting_branch_id`)");
  DBUtil.foreignKeyCheck(database, "branchSettings");

  database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `_new_branches` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT NOT NULL, `address` TEXT, `lat` TEXT, `lng` TEXT, `is_default` INTEGER, `email` TEXT, `phone` TEXT, `clover_category_id` TEXT, `clover_gift_item` TEXT, `clover_cashless_item` TEXT, `prep_time` INTEGER, `opening_hours` TEXT, `currency_code` TEXT, `created_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, `updated_at` INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");


  database.execSQL("INSERT INTO `_new_` (`id`,`name`,`address`,`lat`,`lng`,`is_default`,`email`,`phone`,`prep_time`,`opening_hours`,`currency_code`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) SELECT `id`,`name`,`address`,`lat`,`lng`,`is_default`,`email`,`phone`,`prep_time`,`opening_hours`,`currency_code`,`created_at`,`updated_at` FROM `branches`");


  database.execSQL("DROP TABLE `branches`");
  database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE `_new_` RENAME TO `branches`");
  //this.callback.onPostMigrate(database); /* I believe not needed in actual code as generated code should do this as needed */
```

- You may wish to replace `????WASNULL`, `-9999` and `-8888` with more acceptable values and perhaps include a following UPADTE to alter/calculate the values.

  - although the replacements may never be used.
  - see [coalesce scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce) or perhaps use the [ifnull scalar function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) if preferred, they both work the same, just coalesce is a little more flexible, not that the flexibility is needed in this case.
  - coalesce is more noticeable, hence the use rather than ifnull.

Comment: Yeah I can see a few issues with auto migrations on the issue tracker now I've taken a look, so this looks like a bug in the library